# Make slide out up to icon img

Tags: css

I want to make icon img to slide out up any suggestions ?
like social icons in this website : http://trydo.rainbowit.net/dark-portfolio-landing#portfolio

```css
.move-left
{
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
.move-left img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  cursor: pointer;


}
```

```html
            <div class="move-left">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"><img        src="facebook.svg" height="16px"></a></li>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.`li` MUST be children of a `ul/ol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you intend to move the `img` when all of your `transform` and `transition` properties are on `.move-left`.

I've fixed your HTML as well as per @Paulie_D's comment.

```css
.move-left {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.move-left:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="move-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/3885/facebook.svg" height="16px"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to move the image only when you hover on it specifically, just switch `.move-left` for `img` in your CSS.

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="move-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/3885/facebook.svg" height="16px"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working , But still have a little issue when I come over near the icon effects appears , I just want effect when I hover on the icon specify !!

Comment: You could either (a) look at the edit thats been made or (b) set the display of the ul to `inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: @EnesS I've added the snippet you requested. The reason the hover effect is happening when you move near is that the .move-left `div` takes up 100% of its width which in this case, is the full viewport width.